# Folder on left side of the dock

Tags: macos, dock

I would like to add a folder to the left side of my Dock. When I try to do this it isn’t accepted. However, I can add it to the right side of my Dock. This doesn’t suit me for this particular folder.

**My question is:** Is there any way to add a folder to the left side of the Dock?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but it may not behave the way you want.

What I mean is that adding a folder to the right-hand side of the Dock allows it to *spring* open, and also provides you with options as to how its contents should be viewed and sorted. Placing it on the left-hand side does nothing except open the folder for you within the Finder. If this is acceptable, then follow these steps:

1. Wthin the Finder, select your folder and press <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> (or go to File > Get Info)
2. In the Get Info window that pops up, you’ll see a Name & Extension field. Add .app to the end of the folder name.
3. Press <kbd>return</kbd> and in the pop-up window that appears, click on the <kbd>Add</kbd> button
4. You’ll notice that the folder icon has changed - ignore this for now and leave the Get Info window open
5. Now add the folder to the location you want
6. Now go back to the Get Info window and remove the .app you added to the folder name at Step 2
7. Press <kbd>return</kbd> and in the pop-up window that appears, click on the <kbd>Remove</kbd> button
8. You can now close the Get Info window

In a few moments the folder’s icon should return to normal and you can now click on it within the Dock. Remember, doing so will only open the folder in the Finder.

**Note:** If you ever accidentally remove the folder from the Dock you will need to repeat the 8 steps above. However, you may find you need to restart your Mac **before** doing so.